# GRPC IOS Client Connection Lost -Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, grpc, grpc-java

For the IOS App the connection works , but after the phone is idle for a while , the connection is lost, as such the RPC calls hangs, without any response.

I had the same issue in JAVA, there I added a DeadLine and rebuilt the channel when the Deadline Exceeded, something like below.

```
stub.withDeadlineAfter(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).execute(input, new StreamObserver<AgentGuardStringResponse>() { ... }
```

Then on error (deadline exceeded)

```
mChannel.shutdown();
```

This works fine.

For objective-c/ios

I set a time out for the RPC calls as so

```
  
  [call setTimeout:timeout];
  call.requestHeaders[@"sessionId"] = sessionId;
  [call start];
```

And Try to rebuild ,

```
_serviceClient = [[AgentGuardService alloc] initWithHost:GRPCMetadata.shared.uri];
```

This does not seem to work as the app stays idle for a while after starting and eventually the Requests start flowing through.

Any pointers/guides will be highly helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Which version are you using? This was an issue in old versions of gRPC but recently this problem should have been much better as gRPC switched to use Apple's API in networking layer. If you are experiencing this with v1.21 or a version after that you may come up with a reproduction and [file issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues).

Comment: well in the end i fixed the issue by setting ```setKeepaliveWithInterval``` as
```[GRPCCall setKeepaliveWithInterval:10000 timeout:10000 forHost:GRPCMetadata.shared.uri];```